# Error installing perl6 using rakudobrew: panda library installation fails

Tags: software-installation, perl

I'm trying to install perl6 as a local user using [rakudobrew](http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/):

```
git clone https://github.com/tadzik/rakudobrew ~/.rakudobrew
**add ~/.rakudobrew/bin to path**
rakudobrew build moar
rakudobrew build panda
panda install Task::Star
```

My problem seems to come when trying to build panda:

```
error: pathspec 'nom' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Is there something else I should be adding to my path?

What am I missing?

For full context, here is the complete error message:

```
rob@Desktop:~/.rakudobrew/bin$ ./rakudobrew build panda
Cloning into 'panda'...
remote: Counting objects: 4961, done.
remote: Total 4961 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 4961
Receiving objects: 100% (4961/4961), 870.39 KiB | 514.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2255/2255), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
error: pathspec 'nom' did not match any file(s) known to git.
panda for nom not found
Installing latest panda instead.
==> Bootstrapping Panda
==> Installing panda from a local directory '/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda'
==> panda depends on File::Find, Shell::Command, JSON::Fast, File::Which
==> Shell::Command depends on File::Find
==> Fetching File::Find
==> Building File::Find
==> Testing File::Find
t/01-file-find.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=11,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.00 sys +  1.47 cusr  0.11 csys =  1.61 CPU)
Result: PASS
==> Installing File::Find
==> Successfully installed File::Find
==> Fetching Shell::Command
==> Building Shell::Command
==> Testing Shell::Command
Cannot look up attributes in a IO::Path type object
  in block <unit> at t/02-shell-command.t line 47

# Looks like you planned 16 tests, but ran 14
t/02-shell-command.t .. 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 2/16 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/02-shell-command.t (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 14 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 16 tests but ran 14.
Files=1, Tests=14,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.00 sys +  0.56 cusr  0.06 csys =  0.65 CPU)
Result: FAIL
The spawned command 'prove' exited unsuccessfully (exit code: 1)
   at SETTING::src/core/Exception.pm:63  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:throw)
 from SETTING::src/core/Proc.pm:138  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:sink)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda/Common.pm (Panda::Common):85  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/FF/FF022C174A5E69836C5EB7F5E1D604142A8A90E8:)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda/Common.pm (Panda::Common):85  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/FF/FF022C174A5E69836C5EB7F5E1D604142A8A90E8:)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda/Common.pm (Panda::Common):71  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/FF/FF022C174A5E69836C5EB7F5E1D604142A8A90E8:run-and-gather-output)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda/Tester.pm (Panda::Tester):29  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/1B/1BB66AAAA20A0D0E7F6EB9DEEDBF8B28F28EB941:)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda/Common.pm (Panda::Common):37  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/FF/FF022C174A5E69836C5EB7F5E1D604142A8A90E8:withp6lib)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda/Tester.pm (Panda::Tester):17  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/1B/1BB66AAAA20A0D0E7F6EB9DEEDBF8B28F28EB941:)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda/Tester.pm (Panda::Tester):16  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/1B/1BB66AAAA20A0D0E7F6EB9DEEDBF8B28F28EB941:)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda/Common.pm (Panda::Common):20  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/FF/FF022C174A5E69836C5EB7F5E1D604142A8A90E8:indir)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda/Tester.pm (Panda::Tester):5  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/1B/1BB66AAAA20A0D0E7F6EB9DEEDBF8B28F28EB941:test)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda.pm (Panda):185  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/65/65C91FE4E3E72018680A835ED6FB2D1E57373DB3:)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda.pm (Panda):170  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/65/65C91FE4E3E72018680A835ED6FB2D1E57373DB3:install)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda.pm (Panda):258  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/65/65C91FE4E3E72018680A835ED6FB2D1E57373DB3:)
 from SETTING::src/core/Any-iterable-methods.pm:462  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:)
 from SETTING::src/core/Any-iterable-methods.pm:448  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:sink-all)
 from SETTING::src/core/Seq.pm:184  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:sink)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda.pm (Panda):258  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/65/65C91FE4E3E72018680A835ED6FB2D1E57373DB3:)
 from /home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/lib/Panda.pm (Panda):252  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/panda/ext/File__Find/lib/.precomp/053758C8915A5E3DCEB73F36131D86003BC0AF7C.1483801492.70597/65/65C91FE4E3E72018680A835ED6FB2D1E57373DB3:resolve)
 from bin/panda:20  (<ephemeral file>:)
 from SETTING::src/core/Any-iterable-methods.pm:462  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:)
 from SETTING::src/core/Any-iterable-methods.pm:448  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:sink-all)
 from SETTING::src/core/Seq.pm:184  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:sink)
 from bin/panda:19  (<ephemeral file>:MAIN)
 from bin/panda:16  (<ephemeral file>:MAIN)
 from SETTING::src/core/Main.pm:195  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:MAIN_HELPER)
 from bin/panda:165  (<ephemeral file>:<unit>)
 from bin/panda:1  (<ephemeral file>:<unit-outer>)
 from gen/moar/stage2/NQPHLL.nqp:1582  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/nqp/lib/NQPHLL.moarvm:eval)
 from gen/moar/stage2/NQPHLL.nqp:1785  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/nqp/lib/NQPHLL.moarvm:evalfiles)
 from gen/moar/stage2/NQPHLL.nqp:1679  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/nqp/lib/NQPHLL.moarvm:command_eval)
 from src/Perl6/Compiler.nqp:27  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/nqp/lib/Perl6/Compiler.moarvm:command_eval)
 from gen/moar/stage2/NQPHLL.nqp:1653  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/nqp/lib/NQPHLL.moarvm:command_line)
 from gen/moar/main.nqp:47  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm:MAIN)
 from gen/moar/main.nqp:38  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm:<mainline>)
 from <unknown>:1  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm:<main>)
 from <unknown>:1  (/home/rob/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.moarvm:<entry>)
The spawned command '/home/rob/.rakudobrew/bin/../moar-nom/install/bin/perl6' exited unsuccessfully (exit code: 1)
  in sub MAIN at bootstrap.pl line 68
  in block <unit> at bootstrap.pl line 9

Failed running /home/rob/.rakudobrew/bin/../moar-nom/install/bin/perl6 bootstrap.pl at ./rakudobrew line 58.
        main::run('/home/rob/.rakudobrew/bin/../moar-nom/install/bin/perl6 boots...') called at ./rakudobrew line 528
        main::build_panda(undef, undef) called at ./rakudobrew line 352
        main::build_impl('panda', undef, '') called at ./rakudobrew line 116
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently zef is a better package installer than panda anyway.

I replaced the

```
rakudobrew build panda
panda install Task::Star
```

lines with

```
rakudobrew build zef
zef install Task::Star
```

although Task::Star is also unnecessary if you want to just install packages as you need them.